# Mathematica gives $RecursionLimit to every single input

Tags: warning-messages, recursion, wolfram-cloud

I have been using Mathematica Cloud for about 3 months. About twice a month I encounter a strange and perplexing error that I have, until now, overlooked as an immovable bug. Every function I input, including ones I have previously tested to work correctly, returns a stack of $RecursionLimit : Recursion Depth exceeded during evaluation of x y z. This error persists to absolutely any inputs whatsoever, including basic arithmetic. However, after 30 minutes too, at the longest, 2 hours, the program is running again as though nothing had happened. Does anyone have an insights or possible fixes to the bug. I have found several posts regarding RecursionLimit; yet, none of them pertain to my bug.

Thanks,

Jackie

Comment: I recommend you report this to Wolfram Support. If it’s a server-side issue, as it seems to be, they are the only ones that could fix it.